# Image map (each image is a hyperlink) in montage

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I want to make thumbnails in a montage hyperlinked (image map). Is it possible to do it with Imagemagick? For example when a montage is generated, the hyperlinks get embedded from a text file according to the thumbnail image file name. Or is there a tool for Ubuntu which can do it?

There is [an example here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map). If you hover your mouse over a person in the image, there is a hyperlink to an article about that person.

Comment: should be possible with a shell script, rails, other tech(possibly js).  More info needed regarding environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [the Imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/). [The section on 'image map'](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#html) has it all.

Comment: You must not paste the link but also explain the link

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want, but this:

```
montage -size 64x64 -geometry +5+5 -tile 3x 'img/*.jpg' images.html
```

would create an `images.html` file, that shows the montage file 'images.png' (= thumbnails of size 64x64, 5px spacing, 3 columns) and already correctly links the thumbs to the images in the `img` folder. No need to change the links via a text file.

For more examples, take a look at ImageMagick's [example page for the montage tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#index).

For detailed information on montage's options, see ImageMagick's [montage tool page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php).